# Help needed to connect Brother MFC-L3750CDW to computer with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, printing, brother

I am brand new to Linux and Ubuntu so apologies if this is a dumb question. I had previously installed my printer and successfully printed a document, but it is now no longer working. The system recognises the printer and says it is ready, but when you try to print anything including a test page, it never leaves the queue.

This is the information under printer settings:

Name: MFC_L3750CDW_series
Location:
Address: http://MFC-L3750CDW series._ipp._tcp.local:631
Driver: Brother Brother MFC-L3750CDW series[en]

I should also say that when you click on search for drivers, it says no suitable driver can be found. When I select from the database, this is what comes up:

Address: http://MFC-L3750CDW series._ipp._tcp.local:631
Driver: driverless:ipp://MFC-L3750CDW%20series._ipp._tcp.local/

When you then close the window down and go back in, it defaults to the first option.

I have searched and tried a number of fixes and I do NOT want to do anything stupid! The Brother instructions are pretty ordinary so I'm stumped. Can anyone help please?

Comment: have you tried to do the setup from your printers side,as in make the printer search for the computer on your network and take it from there.

Comment: Yes, still no luck. I have worked out it is an issues with CUPS and have tried to follow the advice given in other questions, but it hasn't helped.